# What is the best way to position custom badges on Woocommerce prodcut loop in Shop

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

**Question**: How do you hook straight into the product thumbnail html on shop page `attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail`? Or instead, how would you recommend the best way to position a custom badge `bottom: 0` absolute to the product image?

My goal is to add custom badges to products on the WooCommerce shop page and have the badges positioned at the bottom of the product image thumbnail.

To start, I created a function using the hook `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` - However, this hook means the tags by default are set to display above the product image.

I then added CSS to get them into position by making the `il.product position: relative` and custom badges `position: absolute` with z-index and pushed it 293px from the top into the desired position.

So it looks like this.

[image]

However, I now realize this workaround is flawed and not really optimal, as it's only specific to my display and thumbnail sizes can change as columns change etc.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Example PHP Function, Simplified.

```
function woo_property_badges() {  
    global $post;
    ?>
    <div class="woo-property-badge">
<span class="woo-property-featured-badge">'Featured'</span>
<span class="woo-property-cat-badge">'Category'</span>
    </div>
<?php } 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woo_property_badges', 1 );
```

Example HTML Output

```
<li class="product type-product post-210012 status-publish first instock product_cat-residential-property has-post-thumbnail featured virtual taxable purchasable product-type-auction et_pb_shop_item_0_0">
<a href="/product/Test-Product/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">   

<div class="woo-property-badge">
<span class="woo-property-featured-badge">Featured</span>
<span class="woo-property-cat-badge">Residential</span>
</div>
```

Test Product Title

CSS Used

```
il.product-type-auction {
  position: relative;
}

.woocommerce span.woo-property-featured-badge {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 293px;
    display: block;
  z-index: 2;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #31324E;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
}

.woocommerce span.woo-property-cat-badge{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #A7784A73 , #A7784A);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 293px;
    right: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.woocommerce span.woo-property-cat-badge:before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: -12px;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid #A7784A73;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is to create a wrapper around the product image so that you can position the badge relative to this wrapper.

```
function wrap_loop_product_image() {

    if ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) return; //* exit early if WooCommerce not active/installed

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' , 'product_loop_image_wrapper_open', 9 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' , 'product_loop_image_wrapper_close', 9 );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' , 'wrap_loop_product_image', 3 );

// Open wrapper
function product_loop_image_wrapper_open() {
    echo '<span class="product-image-wrapper">';
}

// Close wrapper
function product_loop_image_wrapper_close() {
    echo '</span>';
}
```

This code goes in functions.php. You would still need to adjust your CSS code.

Comment: Hi Junky. Thanks for taking the time to provide a suggestion. Unfortunately, in doing so, 'float: right;' does not implement for cat-badge and the container goes to the bottom of the whole product li instead of the thumbnail.

Comment: See my updated answer. Try inserting a wrapper around the product image to allow for more precise positioning.

Comment: Thank you Junky. Perfect idea and worked a treat. Applied some CSS such as making 'span.product-image-wrapper {position: relative; display: block;}' and set up the postion of the product badge div to bottom as desired. All done. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Junky. Could I please ask another quick question in relation to the product wrapper? I have noticed that when I use shortcodes or woo related products on the product page without pagination, then the image wrapper function doesn't work / apply. Any ideas why?

Comment: It could be the priority? Try adjusting the 9 to something higher or lower. Could also be the shortcode or is removing or overriding this action?